# Find the graph given an edge_iter

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-graph

I'm trying to make a function where I give a graph, an edge, and another graph as parameters.

```
bool gUe(Graph& g, edge_iter ep, Graph t)
{

    vertex_t from = source(*ep, t);
    vertex_t to = target(*ep, t);

    Graph::edge_descriptor copied_edge = boost::add_edge(from, to, t[*ep], g).first;

    g[source(copied_edge, g)] = t[from];
    g[target(copied_edge, g)] = t[to];
    return vf2_subgraph_iso(g,t,my_callback())

}
```

The edge is added to the first graph and then I will test if `g` is `vf2_subgraph_iso` with `t`. The result here is always true (if the two graphs are connexe), because the edge `ep` is considered as an edge from `t` before the addition process.

How can I know from which original graph comes `ep` without giving it as:

```
t[*ep]
```

Comment: there is no way documented to get  from the iterator to the containing graph. You need to require callers to call with a certain contract

Comment: @sehe What do you mean by callers ?

Comment: Functions are being called. The code where the function call happens is known as "calling code" or "caller" (in other words, callers need to either pass an edge iterator from the documented graph, or indicate it with a flag; this documented agreement is the contract; what will happen when the caller violates the contract is undefined ([undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)))